# How can I write a regex that will match a nested [quote] BB tag?

Tags: regex

As part of a forum that uses BBCode to store posts, I'm trying to write a way to detect mentions and quotes, in order to notify the users.

I have it working for all cases except nested quotes.

This is my regex so far (Python 2.7):

```py
regex = r'\[url=.*?\/users\/(.*?)\/\]@.*?\[\/url\]|\[quote="(.*?)"\].*?\[\/quote\]'
```

These are my test cases:

```
# This works fine, I get the `user1` group.
Hello [url=/users/user1/]@Foo Bar[/url]

# This works fine, I get the `user2` and `user3` groups.
[quote="user2"]Test message[/quote] OK [quote="user3"]Test message[/quote]

# This doesn't work as I'd l ike. I only get the `user4` group, but not `user5`.
[quote="user4"][quote="user5"]Test message[/quote][/quote]
```

How can I modify the regular expression to match also the third test with the nested `[quote]` block?

Here's a link to regex101 for your convenience: https://regex101.com/r/Ov5SI1/1

Thank you!

Comment: `\[url=.*?\/users\/(.*?)\/\]@.*?\[\/url\]|\[quote=\"(.*?)\"\]` - Try this

Comment: Perfect and simple, thanks! Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor change in the original regex will solve your problem. Here is the original regex:

```
\[url=.*?\/users\/(.*?)\/\]@.*?\[\/url\]|\[quote="(.*?)"\].*?\[\/quote\]
```

---

### Error

Consider the input string:

```
[quote="user4"][quote="user5"]Test message[/quote][/quote]
```

The last alternation tries to match it and it does succeed. However, the first match is

```
[quote="user4"][quote="user5"]Test message[/quote]
```

Now the next match starts after the `[/quote]`. It will not start anywhere before since all the previous text is already part of a successful match.

---

### Correction

*Solution 1:*

Changing this part `.*?\[\/quote\]` in the original regex to a look ahead will result in successful match of both the `user4` and `user5`.

```
\[quote=\"(.*?)\"\](?=.*?\[\/quote\])

final regex: \[url=.*?\/users\/(.*?)\/\]@.*?\[\/url\]|\[quote=\"(.*?)\"\](?=.*?\[\/quote\])
```

*Solution 2:*

Focusing on just the right part of the alternation - `\[quote="(.*?)"\].*?\[\/quote\]`

Here only `\[quote="(.*?)"\]` this is necessary if you want to find any patter of the form `[quote="..."]`. The remaining portion is unnecessary.

Here is the final regex:

```
\[url=.*?\/users\/(.*?)\/\]@.*?\[\/url\]|\[quote=\"(.*?)\"\]
```

---

Please do remember that the regex must be applied globally to find all the matches.